# How to Access correctly to Positions Property in a LinePlot with Ilnumerics?

Tags: c#, ilnumerics

i would like to access to the coordinate information in a LinePlot, i wanto to use the Property `LinePlot.Positions` as show in the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using ILNumerics.Data;
using ILNumerics.Drawing.Plotting;
using ILNumerics.Drawing;
using ILNumerics;
using static ILNumerics.ILMath;
using System.Linq;

namespace TestConsoleUI2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)

         {
            Array<double> xx = linspace(10, 15, 5);
            Array<double> yy = linspace(8, 90, 5);

            LinePlot myLinePlot = new LinePlot(xx, yy);

            RetArray<float> p = myLinePlot.Positions;

          }
    }
}
```

Nevertheless i got an `System.NullReferenceException` i have debugged and the data exists at that moment,
can anyone help me?

Regards

Comment: Can you create [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: From that single line of code, it is impossible to find the cause of your problem. Either dividedDataSets or LinePlot is null. Or if they are properties, some object that is used in the getter is null.

Comment: sorry i just wanted to keep it simple, i just tested the edit coded and still bring the Exception @PrasadTelkikar SomeBody

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After try and error i found the solution that is working for me.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using ILNumerics.Data;
using ILNumerics.Drawing.Plotting;
using ILNumerics.Drawing;
using ILNumerics;
using static ILNumerics.ILMath;
using System.Linq;

namespace TestConsoleUI2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)

         {
            Array<double> xx = linspace(10, 15, 5);
            Array<double> yy = linspace(8, 90, 5);

            LinePlot myLinePlot = new LinePlot(xx, yy);

            PositionsBuffer p = myLinePlot.Line.Positions;

          }
    }
}
```